# Fully securing a directory

Tags: security, apache, hosting

What are the different approaches to securing a directory?

> including an index page so contents can't be viewed

the problem with this is that people can still access the files if they know the filename they're after

> including an htaccess file to deny all

this seems to be the best approach, but is there any case that an htaccess file can be passed by? are there any cases as well where htaccess is not available?

> restricting folder access

this is also a nice solution, but the problem is, the folder I'm trying to secure should be viewable and writable by the program.

Are there any other ways that folder security can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice for Apache is to use htaccess to restrict - this only restricts from the webserver - but that should be what you need. You can add authentication into this - but for most needs to you can just deny all acess - which hides the directory completely.

Another method that can also work well with using htaccess to deny direct access would be to use htaccess in your route directory to rewrite urls. This means that a request such as /example/listItems/username/ted can be rewritten as a call to a php or other file such as:

/application/index.php?module=listItems&username=ted

The advantage of doing this is that the webserver does not give out paths to any directories so it is much more difficult for people to hack around looking for directories.

If you want to protect a directory of images you could also use htaccess to redirect to a different directory so that /images/image5.png is actually a call to :

/application/images/image5.png

Comment: I also think that securing a directory with htaccess is by far the easiest and simplest way to do it. 

What I'm concerned about is is there a way for htaccess to "not work"? Would there be any hosting environments that disables htaccess? (I think IIS doesn't use htaccess, so please assume that all of this would be working on Apache)

Comment: You right I can't definitely say that someone might go out of their way to disable htaccess - but think that it would be very unlikely.

Comment: In you average, day-to-day shared hosting account, htaccess usually works, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try not placing your protected directory under your www dir but on other "non www visible" location. If your app needs to read / write data, tell it to do it on the other location. Modify its properties so only the app has the proper rights to do so.

Comment: I also thought about using this process, but I want my app to be as idiot proof as possible, mostly just upload + install via web-installer. If all else fails, this would be the way to go for my app.